# How to execute a custom React Query hook after an event inside an application?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am a React Query newbie.

I am learning how to use React Query to fetch data from an API endpoint. I am using JSONPlaceholder fake API to fetch a list of posts.

When I click on the `All Posts` button, I get a list of posts. (when there are no values inside the search box, the `Search` button remains disabled).

[image]

And when I type a number in the search box and click on the `Search` button, I see one post whose id matches the number in the search bar. (when there are values inside the search box, the `All Posts` button remains disabled).

[image]

Everything is fine till now. But there is a minor issue: **I see loading indicators (Loading...) even before I have clicked on a button**. For example, the moment I type a number inside the search bar, I see a loading indicator. This is because the react query hooks are being executed when the `Posts` component renders. (Is my understanding correct here?)

**What do I want?**

I want the custom hooks  `useFetchPosts` & `useFetchPost` to be executed **AFTER** I click on the buttons `All Posts` & `Search` respectively, so that I don't see the loading... indicators even before I have clicked the buttons to fetch posts.

My files are as follows:

**Posts.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useFetchPosts } from "./customHooks/queryHooks";
import { useFetchPost } from "./customHooks/queryHooks";

const Posts = () => {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(null);
  const [singlePost, setSinglePost] = useState(null);

  const { data, error, isError, isLoading } = useFetchPosts();
  const {
    data: postData,
    error: postError,
    isError: postIsError,
    isLoading: postIsLoading,
  } = useFetchPost(searchQuery);

  const handlePostList = () => {
    setPosts(data);
  };

  const handlePostItem = () => {
    setSinglePost(postData);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="search-container">
        <input
          type="number"
          value={searchQuery}
          onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
          type="submit"
          disabled={searchQuery === ""}
          onClick={handlePostItem}
        >
          Search
        </button>
        <button
          type="submit"
          disabled={searchQuery !== ""}
          onClick={handlePostList}
        >
          All Users
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="user-list">
        <ul>
          {isLoading ? (
            <p>Loading...</p>
          ) : isError ? (
            <p>{error.message}</p>
          ) : (
            posts &&
            searchQuery === "" &&
            posts.map((post) => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)
          )}
        </ul>
        <ul>
          {postIsLoading ? (
            <p>Loading...</p>
          ) : postIsError ? (
            <p>{postError.message}</p>
          ) : (
            <li>{singlePost && searchQuery !== "" && singlePost.title}</li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Posts;
```

queryHooks.js

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

export const useFetchPosts = () => {
  const result = useQuery(["posts"], async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`
    );
    return data;
  });

  return result;
};

export const useFetchPost = (searchQuery) => {
  const result = useQuery(["posts", searchQuery], async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${searchQuery}`
    );
    return data;
  });

  return result;
};
```

**GitHub Repo**: https://github.com/sundaray/learn-react-query.git

Answer (score 0):

React-Query come with an option for that, you need to add the "enabled" option and once the condition you pass is true you query will be launched, more info [Here](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/guides/disabling-queries)